# How to list files and their inode numbers in current directory?

Tags: command-line, files, inode

How can I obtain  list of items and their inode numbers in the current working directory ?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel A comment ? That's an interesting reason. Can you explain what exactly you mean ?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel  It's intended as "canonical" question for the site, which can be used to close other questions. If someone comes with the same question, we can use this one as duplicate.  But to argue the case, many canonical questions themselves look simplistic and "lacking research", and for a good reason - they're intended as questions that address the basics. Take for instance [this one](How to remove all files from a directory?
).  I'm sure at the time when the question was creted, stackoverflow already had one; problem is that you can't close question on site A with link on site B

Comment: Makes  sense. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Today this question reached 1000 views. I think this serves as a somewhat testimony that it is a useful question

Comment: I agree. And I'll remove my older comments, as they are just confusing now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ls` has `-i` flag:

```
$ ls -i
1054235 a.out  1094297 filename.txt
```

But if you are feeling adventurous , build `ls -i` yourself:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

void print_dirents(DIR * dir){
    struct dirent *entry;
    while ( (entry=readdir(dir)) != NULL ){
        printf("%s,%d\n",entry->d_name,entry->d_ino);
    }
}

int main(){

    char current_dir[PATH_MAX];
    DIR *cwd_p;

    if (  getcwd(current_dir,sizeof(current_dir)) != NULL){
        cwd_p = opendir(current_dir);
        print_dirents(cwd_p);
        closedir(cwd_p);
    } else {
        perror("NULL pointer returned from getcwd()");
    }

return 0;
}
```

And it works as so:

```
$ gcc lsi.c && ./a.out
filename.txt,1094297
a.out,1054235
..,1068492
.,1122721
lsi.c,1094294
```

Answer (score 4):

```
stat ./*
```

or

```
man stat; stat --format=*f* ./*
```

Comment: I had to do `stat --format='%i %n' ./*`